# Same function is giving different results in opposite order in Python. Why?

Tags: python, function, return

I'm using this code:

```
def copy_part_of_space(row,column,lenght):
    #Copy String to Presentation Space (15)
    #Prerequisite Connect Presentation Space
    #Prerequisite function: connect_pcomm(presentation_space)    
    function_number = c_int(8)
    data_string = create_string_buffer(lenght*2*2) #number of unicode char *2*2
    lenght = c_int(lenght)
    ps_position = c_int(((row - 1) * 80)+ column)
    foo = hllapi(byref(function_number), data_string, byref(lenght), byref(ps_position))
    data_string.value
    return {{
        0 : 'The host presentation space contents were copied to the application program. The target presentation space was active, and the keyboard was unlocked.',
        1 : 'Your program is not connected to a host session.',
        4 : 'The host presentation space contents were copied. The connected host     presentation space was waiting for host response.',
        5 : 'The host presentation space was copied. The keyboard was locked.',
        9 : 'A system error was encountered.',
        'x' : 'Undocumented error found. Run in circles.',
        }.get(foo, 'x'),data_string.value}
```

The idea is to copy some information from a terminal; The functions needs to return the status information (using the dictionary and 0,1,4,5,9,x parameters) AND the copied information - using data_string.value

To run some tests I was using this code that uses the function above:

```
for a in range(15,22):
    print copy_part_of_space(a,7,8)
```

This is the results:

```
   set(['The host presentation space contents were copied to the application program. The target presentation space was active, and the keyboard was unlocked.', '36343581'])
   set(['36343663', 'The host presentation space contents were copied to the application program. The target presentation space was active, and the keyboard was unlocked.'])
   set(['The host presentation space contents were copied to the application program. The target presentation space was active, and the keyboard was unlocked.', '36343708'])
   set(['36344673', 'The host presentation space contents were copied to the application program. The target presentation space was active, and the keyboard was unlocked.'])
   set(['36344740', 'The host presentation space contents were copied to the application program. The target presentation space was active, and the keyboard was unlocked.'])
   set(['The host presentation space contents were copied to the application program. The target presentation space was active, and the keyboard was unlocked.', '36344758'])
   set(['36344869', 'The host presentation space contents were copied to the application program. The target presentation space was active, and the keyboard was unlocked.'])
```

As you can see, sometimes I get the status information before what was copied from the host application - like the first line.

But sometimes I get the information that was copied before the status information, like line two.

I am **not** familiar with using `dict` to return information, so I guess that could be a problem, specially when mixing with the fact that I'm trying to return two variables.

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

I know that I could simply use the `dict` and save the return information to a variable before passing the return, but I really thought this is a more elegant solution - am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set)s are unordered (or better, their order is arbitrary). Nothing you can do about this except use an ordered datatype instead.

For example by removing the `set` constructor `{...}`:

```
return {
    0 : 'The host presentation space contents were copied to the application program. The target presentation space was active, and the keyboard was unlocked.',
    1 : 'Your program is not connected to a host session.',
    4 : 'The host presentation space contents were copied. The connected host     presentation space was waiting for host response.',
    5 : 'The host presentation space was copied. The keyboard was locked.',
    9 : 'A system error was encountered.',
    'x' : 'Undocumented error found. Run in circles.',
    }.get(foo, 'x'), data_string.value
```

Now this code returns a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple) instead (the first element is the lookup result from the "error message dictionary", the second one whatever is contained in `data_string.value`).

Comment: `their order is arbitrary` but might change when you do things

Comment: The usual thing to do in this case is to return a tuple.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Which is what happens here when the `set` constructor is removed.

Comment: I think you edited in the example with a tuple while or after I composed my comment.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Probably while you were commenting ;) Ninja edit FTW!

Comment: @TimPietzcker That works perfectly, but shouldn't I be using a pair of () on the return statement? Or is it optional?

Comment: @JohnnyBigoode: It's optional - the comma creates the tuple, the parentheses are only necessary in cases of ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

You're specifically returning a `set`, which is defined to be an unordered datattype.  That is, the elements of a set may be returned in any order.  Sets are optimized for membership testing (`if x in set:`).  Sets are like the keys of a dictionary: they can be iterated over in any order.

I suspect a better data type for you would be a tuple:  `return (a, b)`

Then the results will always be in the same order.

Note the differences in literal notation:

- Dictionary has colons to pair items.: `{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd')`.
- Set has no colons, and is just arbitrary-ordered items: `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}`
- Tuple uses parenthesis: `('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`
- List uses square brackets, and is mutable: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: Tuples are commonly enclosed in parentheses, but it's the commas that make it a tuple so `'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'` is also a tuple. Parentheses are optional except for the empty tuple or where they are needed for syntactic reasons (e.g. in a function's argument list without parens the commas would separate arguments).

Comment: @Duncan: That's true.  They're also required for the one element tuple.  One could say that commas create tuples, when they are not otherwise part of the syntax.

Comment: For a one element tuple you only require the comma, not the parentheses: `x = 1,` will create a tuple.